# hiding/showing fields depending on previous field - issue with hidden field values being submitted

Tags: html, jquery

Having an issue with this form.
My form has a dropdown. Then, a second dropdown appears with options depending on the previous field.
This works visually - but the second dropdown box value being submitted seems only to come from one of the groups.

```js
function oplistfield(that) {
  document.getElementById("uppergilist").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("hepbillist").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("breastlist").style.display = "none";

  if (that.value == "UpperGI") {
    document.getElementById("uppergilist").style.display = '';
  }

  if (that.value == "HepBil") {
    document.getElementById("hepbillist").style.display = '';
  }

  if (that.value == "Breast") {
    document.getElementById("breastlist").style.display = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<?php
  $operation = htmlspecialchars($_POST["operation"]);
?>

<form name="frm1" action="" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Specialty:</td>
      <td>
        <select name="specialty" id="specialty" onchange="oplistfield(this);">
          <option value="select...">please select...</option>
          <option value="Breast">Breast [RVI]</option>
          <option value="HepBil">HepBil [Freeman]</option>
          <option value="UpperGI">UpperGI [RVI]</option>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="uppergilist" style="display: none">
      <td>Operation:</td>
      <td>
        <select id="operation" name="operation">
          <option value="select...">please select...</option>
          <option value="OGD">OGD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="hepbillist" style="display: none">
      <td>Operation:</td>
      <td>
        <select id="operation" name="operation">
          <option value="select...">please select...</option>
          <option value="LapCholehepbil">Lap Chole</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="breastlist" style="display: none">
      <td>Operation type:</td>
      <td>
        <select id="operation" name="operation">
          <option value="select...">please select...</option>
          <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
          <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
          <option value="Major">Major</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Whatever is selected, only the "operation" value from the "breastlist" is sent in the form. If I try and select UpperGI or HepBil, the "operation" value sent is "please select...", which I'm guessing is because it's the first option in "breastlist"

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same name. For them to be received correctly on the server side you need to work with the values as an array.